# PHP Password Hash and Salt

Tags: php, mysql

I know this has been asked before, but I just want to make sure what I've got is up to date and secure for obvious reasons before we go live.

I've used this method to secure passwords:

```
'password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n",
```

This is a user input form to create a new account. My understanding is this hashes the password and uses salt serverside for extra security. Am I right in thinking this or am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you simply take a look at the functions documentation? It explains all the details, that is what the documentation is for... http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Thanks and I've been doing this but I'm new to PHP as a language and just wanted to get a second opinion I hadn't made an obvious error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Am I right in thinking this or am I missing something?"*

It's not what's missing, but what is "too much".

You need to get rid of the `."\n"` in this:

```
'password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n",
```

since it is adding/embedding a hidden linebreak to the hash and will fail *silently* on [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

You can also use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), which is one way of getting rid of it before it gets inserted in your database. But, it's best to just delete it altogether.

This has been stated in a user contributed note in the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017

> *Be care when using the example from the documentation which concatenates a newline character `\n` to the end of the hash, i.e.:
>   `echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";`
>   People are storing the hash with the concatenated newline and consequently `password_verify()` will fail.*

Comment: Thank you for your input I really appreciate it! I've removed the "\n" this was just from a tutorial I followed.